# How to perform group by operation in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> Get count of transactions by region where customers had greater than 10000$ sales and less than 10000$ sales. (hint: create 2 columns for getting count of transaction ids - one where customers had greater than 10000 $ sales and another where customers had less than 10000 $ sales)

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXYcr.png)

I am having trouble figuring out how to go about this problem as transaction_id has all unique values and how do I groupby region in Pandas

```
df_3 = dataset.groupby(['region', 'transaction_id'], as_index=False)['sales'].sum()
df_3
```

[above code give the following output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIYpE.png)

[and then from df_3 I got the sales values >10,000 and <10000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P9VM.png)
But I don't know how to get count of transactions by region

Comment: 1- mask the non matching rows, 2- `groupby`+`count`

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Not if you don't provide a clean minimal reproducible example and your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is the solution you are finding. Do upvote and accept solution if it help.

```
dataset.loc[dataset["sales"] < 10000, "10k_above"] = 0
dataset.loc[dataset["sales"] >= 10000, "10k_above"] = 1

df_results = dataset.groupby(by=["region"], as_index=False).agg(
    transaction_count = ("transaction_id", "count"),
    above_10k_count = ("10k_above", "sum")
    below_10k_count = ("10k_above", lambda x: (x==0).sum())
)
```

Comment: Any idea how this can be done in mysql also?